# Linux C++ Serial Port Reading/Writing

Tags: c++, multithreading, serial-port

I'm trying to read data that I've written to the serial port `/tty/USBS0`. I've opened the port through `serial_fd = open(serialport.str().c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);`, and I am writing data through `retVal2 = write(serial_fd, (void *)&msg, length);`.

However, I am running into an issue where when I call read(), it stops there; in other words, it continues to read indefinitely.

```
void cmgGSP::read_thread(){ 

unsigned char msg[256];
unsigned char messagelength;
msg_header msgHeader; //msg_header is defined in cmgCOM.h
msgHeader.startByte = 0;
msgHeader.length = 0;
msgHeader.ID = 0;
int totalBytes;
int retVal;
cout<<"Scope Test -- In Read Thread"<<endl;

while(1) //infinte loop, since we're going to want to always be reading command data

{

cout<<"Scope Test -- In While(1)"<< endl;

    totalBytes = 0;
    while (totalBytes == 0) {
        cout<<"Scope Test -- First While Loop"<<endl;

        retVal = read(serial_fd, (unsigned char*)&msgHeader, 1);
        cout<<"retVal: "<<retVal <<endl; //This does not get printed

        if (retVal == -1)
        {
            printf("read() message failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        if (msgHeader.startByte != FROM_CMG) {
            printf("Bad start byte on read()\n");
            totalBytes = 0;

        } else {

            cout<<"scope test 2"<<endl;

            totalBytes+=retVal;

        }

    }



    while (totalBytes < sizeof(msgHeader)) {

retVal = read(serial_fd, (unsigned char*)&msgHeader+totalBytes, sizeof(msgHeader)-totalBytes);

        cout<< "in second while"<<endl;         

        if (retVal == -1){
            printf("read() message failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
        totalBytes+=retVal;

    }

    if (msgHeader.startByte != START_BYTE) {
        printf("Bad start byte on message\n");
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("MSG RCV: StartByte=0x%X, Length=0x%X, ID=0x%X\n", msgHeader.startByte, msgHeader.ID, msgHeader.length);

        break;
    }
}
}
```

Above is the thread that I have created; however, the output never makes it past "Scope Test -- First While Loop". Even when I have explicitly called the thread after I write data, the result is the same: it reads infinitely. I know it's actually reading because if I disconnect the board while it's stuck, it starts printing "read() message failed ..."

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Any reason for not using QtSerialPort?

Comment: I was not aware of QtSerialPort, but from the description on the site ("Qt Serial Port provides the basic functionality, which includes configuring, I/O operations, getting and setting the control signals of the RS-232 pinouts.") this wouldn't be an optimal solution since we're connecting USB to RS-422.

Comment: It works fine for that, too.

Comment: But would that fix the issue with read()? I don't think we're having an issue in opening/connecting to the serial port.

Comment: Well, it would be easy to test by running any of the reading command line example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need O_NONBLOCK flag to be set in the open system call; that way depending upon the data written to the port, you will exit out of read() and error out/ get the filled buffer.

"If some process has the pipe open for writing and O_NONBLOCK is clear, read() will block the calling thread until some data is written or the pipe is closed by all processes that had the pipe open for writing."

Read about the O_NONBLOCK flag here:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/read.html

Comment: How/where would I add the O_NONBLOCK to the read call? Can you give an example, please? I tried adding it to open(), and that didn't help; I tried adding it to read() and it threw a compiler error stating that read() had too many arguments.

Comment: Did it still hang in the read() even after you passed the flag to open() ?

Comment: Yes, it did still hang.

Comment: How are you writing the data to the port ?

Comment: I am writing data through `write(serial_fd, (void *)&msg, length);`, where `serial_fd` is the value set when we opened the port (see top of question).
This is where we're calling write, and where msg is.
http://pastie.org/9378572

Comment: Can you confirm that the write() is actually putting the data? Did you check the return value of write() ? How many bytes written is it returning?